# Oracle full text, the syntax of CONTAINS()

Tags: oracle, full-text-search

```
contains(columnname, 'ABC')=0
```

this means search for the data which doesn't contain word 'ABC'

```
contains(columnname, 'ABC and XYZ')=0
contains(columnname, 'ABC or XYZ')=0
```

what do these 2 sql mean? I tested them, there's no syntax error, but they didn't work as I expected, the 'and' seems like  an 'or', and 'or' seems like an 'and', could anyone help to explain this? 
all doc found in google are for contains()>0, those're not what I need.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you, do you mean that you expect the `AND` to become an `OR` (and vice versa) as should be according to De-Morgan laws, but it doesn't ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/text.102/b14218/csql.htm#i997503), the `contains` function :

> returns a relevance score for every row selected

If you ask for

```
contains(columnname, 'ABC')=0
```

You actually ask for a score of `0` which means: columnname doesn't contain 'ABC'

According to the docs:

> In an AND query, the score returned is the score of the lowest query term
>
> In an OR query, the score returned is the score for the highest query term

So if you ask for:

```
contains(columnname, 'ABC and XYZ')=0
```

then if either 'ABC' **or** 'XYZ' has a score of `0` it will have the lowest score and that's what you'll get from the function, so you're actually asking for: columnname doesn't contain 'ABC' or 'XYZ' (at least one of them).

Same thing for the  `or` -

```
contains(columnname, 'ABC or XYZ')=0
```

only if both 'ABC' **and** 'XYZ' have the score of `0` the function will return `0`, so you're actually asking for: columnname doesn't contain 'ABC' and 'XYZ' (both of them).

IMHO, this behaviour is correct since it meets [De-Moragan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. this website is much more powerful than OTN, :)